# Solution check request for the question: If $G=AB$ and $A\cap B=N,$ prove that $G/N\cong A/N\times B/N\\$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, quotient-group, direct-product

Can someone please check my solution to the following question please.

Let $A$ and $B$ $N$ be normal subgroups of a group $G$ such that $N\subset A$, $N \subset B.$  If $G=AB$ and $A\cap B=N,$ prove that $G/N\cong A/N\times B/N\\$

$\textbf{Proof:}$  Let the function $f:G/N\rightarrow A/N \times B/N$ be defined by $f(abN)=(aN, bN)$.  To show $f$ is an isomorphic map, we have to show it is well-defined homomorphic bijective map.

Well-definedness

Let $abN=a'b'N,$ which is equivalent
to $ab\equiv a'b' \pmod N$, then $a'^{-1}ab\equiv b' \pmod N,$ So $a'^{-1}a\equiv 1\pmod N$ and $b\equiv b' \pmod N$ and so $a'^{-1}a\in N$ which gives $a\equiv a' \pmod N$ and $b\equiv b' \pmod N$.  Hence $aN=a'N$ and $bN=b'N$.  Therefore $(aN, bN)=(a'N, b'N).$ This shows $f$ is well-defined.

Homomorphism:

Let $a, a', b, b' \in G$, then $f(aa'bb'N)=(aa'N, bb'N)=(aNa'N, bNb'N)=(aN, bN)(a'N, b'N)=f(abN)f(a'b'N)$ This shows that $f$ is a homomorphic mapping.

Injectivity

Suppose $f(abN)=f(a'b'N)$, then $(aN, bN)=(a'N, b'N)$.  Since  $(a'N, b'N)(a'N, b'N)^{-1}=(a'N, b'N)(a'^{-1}N, b'^{-1}N)=(N,N)$, then $(aa'^{-1}N, bb'^{-1}N)=(N,N).$ But $aa'^{-1}N=N$ and $bb'^{-1}N=N$ means both $aa'^{-1}, bb'^{-1}$ are in $N$, and so $aN= a'N$, $bN=b'N$.  So $aNbN= a'Nb'N=a'b'N= abN\\$  Hence $f$ is injective.

Surjectivity

Suppose $(aN, bN)\in A/N \times B/N$ for any $a\in A, b\in B$, since $G=AB$, then for any $g\in G$ where $g=ab\in AB$.  Then $a=gb^{-1},$ $b=a^{-1}g$.  So if $(aN, bN)\in A/N \times B/N$ implies there exist $gb^{-1}\in A$ and $a^{-1}g\in B$ so that $gb^{-1}a^{-1}gN\in G/N$ for which $f(abN)=(aN,bN)$.  So $f$ is surjective.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You haven't defined $f$.

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki other than that, does my solution look ok?  I copied the solution from my written one and I forgot to mention that little detail.

Comment: Without the definition of $f$, how can we check if the solution is OK? Please edit the post.

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki I just edited the post.

Comment: Some details are not clear. How do you get from "$a'^{-1}ab\equiv b' \pmod N$ to $a'^{-1}a\equiv 1\pmod N$? Or from $abNa'b'N$ to $aa'bb'N$?
It might be easier to apply the isomorphism theorem to the map $G\to G/B\times G/A$, $g\mapsto (gB,gA)$ and then consider $G/B=AB/B\cong A/N$, etc.

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki I am trying to do the question without resorting to the isomorphism theorem.  I know I did not wrote down all the justifications like $abN=aNbN$ or if $ab\equiv a'b' \pmod N$ then $b\equiv b' \pmod N$ and $a\equiv a'\pmod N$, etc

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki do I need to write down those justification steps for purposes of clarity.

Comment: Your proof is essential correct. It's just a little odd that some (easy) details are explained, but others aren't. At some point you need to explain why $abN=baN$ (this is implicitly assumed when you prove homomorphism).

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki why is that fact needed for homomorphism, can I ask?

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki I deliberately multiplied the four elements in those order to make the algebra work out just to avoid to having to show $abN=baN$.   Not sure if that is a good idea.

Comment: You have to show that $f(abN\cdot a'b'N)=f(abN)f(a'b'N)$. This is not convincing so far.

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki thank you for pointing that out to me.  I think I see why I need that missing fact you pointed out.  Much appreciated it.